# Get the financial year from a date in a pandas dataframe and add as new column

Tags: pandas, dataframe, datetime

This must be really simple but can't find the answer - have a dataframe with a date, and i just need to add a financial year column (1st April - 31st March) - e.g. 15/5/19 would return 2019 or 2019-20.

I could probably do it with a for loop, but i'm guessing there is a much better way within the dataframe?

```
if base_date.month > 3:
    fin_year = base_date.year
else:
    fin_year = base_date.year-1
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This will work, assuming your date column is `base_date` and is a datetime object:

```
df['financial_year'] = df['base_date'].map(lambda x: x.year if x.month > 3 else x.year-1)
```

Comment: Worked a treat - thanks :) Is using .map generally better/different than iterating through a for loop?

Comment: Yes, its much cleaner and faster!

Answer (score 10):

Actually, there's a fuction for that:

```
s.dt.to_period('Q-OCT').dt.qyear
```

Comment: I'm sure this works, but i don't understand enough to make it work. I've tried to apply it as: df['Fin_Yr'] = df.to_period('Q-OCT').df.qyear

Comment: `df['Fin_Yr'] = df['your_date_column_name'].dt.to_period('Q-OCT').df.qyear `

Comment: The part `.to_period('Q-OCT')` indicates year ends after October. If you wanted the new fiscal year to start in July then it ends after June so use `.to_period('Q-JUN')` ...

Answer (score 2):

For **Australian** Financial Year:

`df['financial_year'] = df['base_date'].map(lambda d: d.year + 1 if d.month > 6 else d.year)`

Answer (score 1):

`PeriodIndex` objects have the `as_freq` method for recasting to annual series, which allows you to specify the month at which years are deemed to start.

```
df['financial_year'] = df['base_date'].asfreq('A-APR') - 1
```

Subtract 1 to get it to regard the *previous* April as the year start.